# VBA ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(numero).XValues

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code;

I am creating charts in Excel, but a mistake always appears when I am creating xValues. Help me.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
   Dim VectorGrafica(26) As Integer
   Dim cuenta As Integer
   Dim ho As Integer
   Dim ma As Integer
   Dim ejex As Range
   Dim numero As Integer
   Dim ejey As Range    

  cuenta = 0
  da = 1
  If ComboBox3 = "" Or ComboBox4 = "" Then
  MsgBox "No ha determinado el horizonte de tiempo", vbOKOnly, "Horizonte de   tiempo"
 End If

 For s = 24 To 46
 If Controls("CheckBox" & s) = True Then
 cuenta = 1 + cuenta
 VectorGrafica(da) = 1
 da = da + 1
 Else
 VectorGrafica(da) = 0
 da = da + 1
 End If
 Next s

 If cuenta = 0 Then
 MsgBox "No ha seleccionado ningún rubro", vbOKOnly, "Rubros"
 End If

 If cuenta > 0 Then
    numero = 1

    Select Case ComboBox3.ListIndex
    Case 0
    ma = 2
    Case 1
    ma = 3
    Case 2
    ma = 4
    Case 3
    ma = 5
     Case 4
    ma = 6
     Case 5
    ma = 7
     Case 6
    ma = 8
     Case 7
    ma = 9
     Case 8
    ma = 10
     Case 9
    ma = 11
     Case 10
    ma = 12
     Case 11
    ma = 13

    End Select

    Select Case ComboBox4.ListIndex

    Case 0
    ho = 2

    Case 1
    ho = 3

    Case 2
    pa = 4

    Case 3
    ho = 5

    Case 4
    ho = 6

    Case 5
    ho = 7

    Case 6
    ho = 8

    Case 7
    ho = 9

    Case 8
    ho = 10

    Case 9
    ho = 11

    Case 10
    ho = 12

    Case 11
    ho = 13

    End Select

      Dim hola As Range    

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmooth).Select
    For i = 1 To 25
    If VectorGrafica(i) = 1 Then

        ActiveChart.Activate

    Set rangodenombre = Sheets(ComboBox6.Text).Cells(i + 1, 1)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(numero).Name = rangodenombre

  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(numero).XValues = 

_Sheets(ComboBox6.Text).Range(Cells(1, ma), Cells(1, ho))

   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(numero).Values =

 Sheets(ComboBox6.Text).Range(Cells(i + 1, ma), Cells(1 + i, ho))***

    numero = numero + 1

    End If
    Next i       

 End If     
End Sub
```

The part with *** shows me an error, but I don't know why.
I am treating to do chart in Excel. Please help me!

Comment: what error? could you provide an [mvce]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Sheets(ComboBox6.Text).Range(Cells(i + 1, ma), Cells(1 + i, ho))
> ```

The `.Range` call is qualified with a specific `Sheet`.

`Cells` calls, on the other hand, aren't; they're *implicitly* referring to the `ActiveSheet` - if that's not the same sheet `.Range` is qualified with, you can expect an error to happen.

Keep a reference to your sheet with a `With` block, and qualify your `Range` and `Cells` calls with a dot:

```
With Worksheets(comboBox6.Text)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(numero).Values = _
        .Range(.Cells(i + 1, ma), .Cells(i + 1, ho))
End With
```